# Time-based workflows failing to fire - isolated incidents

Tags: workflow, error, time-dependent-workflow

This is the second time now I have witnessed this and I cannot find an answer for why it happens. The first instance happened with a completely different object and workflow a few months ago, but the current situation:

- When a customer support rep closes a support case a trigger will run and create a survey record (a completely different object called Survey__c) setting the type on the survey record to the case type (in this case, the survey type would be "Support").
- We then have a workflow that runs when a record is created to update a field on this survey record (field is called "Send_Now__c", and should be updated to TRUE) 1 hour after it's created. This runs when it sees the survey type of "Support" (the purpose is to send out support surveys 1 hour after case closure).
- We then have a trigger that runs logic based off surveys that have "Send_Now__c" set to TRUE, but this trigger obviously won't run if the time-based workflow won't run.

We have thousands of instances where support surveys are made, the workflow fires and updates "Send_Now__c" without issue. However we just came across a survey that SHOULD have been sent out last month, but the "Send_Now__c" field was never updated. We went back through all our code, looked at the record and tried to figure out why the workflow didn't fire. There are no triggers, workflows, or scheduled classes interfering here. There is no bad/dirty data. We also never received any error emails. Everything about the case that was closed and the survey looks correct except for the fact that the time-based workflow never fired.

Has anyone else had instances where a time-based workflow didn't fire even when it should have? This is the second time we have witnessed a time-based workflow not firing when it SHOULD have. Every other instance where a workflow didn't fire we were able to find the reason behind it. This time we simply see no reason why it wouldn't fire. We also do not have many time-based workflow rules so we are not hitting the hourly limit... and even if we did, the record should still be queued for the next hour.

Our solution for now is to send out an email at the beginning of the day with all the surveys that SHOULD be sent and all the surveys that actually were sent (from the previous day), just so in the future we can catch this and manually update the "Send_Now__c" field. We have never come across an issue in the 6+ years we've been developing on Salesforce that we couldn't fix or solve, but this one is really throwing me off.

Any ideas or similar experiences? Thanks!

Comment: I have had similiar issues with time based workflow recently.  I ended up moving it to Apex. Exact same issue tho, very frustrating.

Comment: We had a similar situation where Processes were involved, and retriggered multiple times - at some point SF didn't consider the record as a new and didn't run any WFR using ISNEW() validations.